# std::function extract and remove argument

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, std-function, stdbind

I'm learning c++11/14 these days and it seems like a whole new language to me with all the great additions but I still can't quite make use of all these new features:

```
typedef std::function<void()> void_f;

typedef std::function<void(int a, void_f b)> f1;
typedef std::function<void(int a, std::function<void(void_f f)> c, void_f b)> f2; // this order is wanted

std::vector<f1> v;

void add(f1 f)
{
    v.push_back(f);
}

void add(f2 f)
{
     v.push_back(f) // ?
 // I want to extract 'void_f f' argument from std::function for later use 
//and remove std::function completely to get same signature as f1
}
```

I've been looking at std::move, std::bind, std::forward, std::placeholders but I can't seem to find anything like this. Maybe I should save longer version in vector and then bind empty lambda for shorter one?

Comment: what do you mean by *"I want to extract 'void_f f' argument from std::function for later use and remove std::function completely"* ?

Comment: A `std::function` is something that can be called with its arguments, not something that *has* arguments?

Comment: **Why** do you want to extract the function pointer from the `std::function`?  What are you hoping that will offer you?  *Note that there may be no function pointer at all*

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect better what I want to achieve. I just want  to save in the same vector holder, but also reuse second argument from std::function<void(void_f arg to save)>

Comment: What do you want to *reuse* ? `f` itself doesn't hold any argument to be *reused*

Comment: f is a void function that can have some code that can be called later on

Comment: the second and third typedef's don't make any sense and don't compile

Comment: sorry, was writing it by hand, forgot the last >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can save the "shorter" f1 in the vector if that's what you want:

```
typedef std::function<void()> void_f;

typedef std::function<void(int a, void_f b)> f1;
typedef std::function<void(int a, std::function<void(void_f f)> c, void_f b)> f2;

std::vector<f1> v;

void add(f1 f)
{
    v.push_back(f);
}

void add(f2 f)
{
     v.push_back([](int a, void_f b) { f(a, [](){}, b); });
}
```

You can't "remove" the extra argument of `f2` but you can pass a no-op lambda. The outer lambda puts the remaining arguments a and b into the right order.

Comment: that was what I've done first but then argument is completely lost. Is there any way to get ahold of it somehow?

Comment: @juzerKicker: Which argument is lost? The whole reason why we provide an empty lambda as a second argument is because there wasn't an argument in the first place. `f2 f` needs 3 arguments, and the users of `vector<f1>` will only provide 2 arguments.

Comment: std::function<void(void_f f)> has f argument, which is lambda, which may contain code written by hand, usage would be like: c([]{} _some_code_here}). I would like to save that before 'removing' it by calling  no-op lambda later on. I think I will do that on the fly once c is called.

Comment: @juzerKicker: Higher-order functions can be confusing. `std::function<void(void_f f)>` doesn't have an `f` argument, it _needs_ an argument.